# Python как вывести результат (в консоли работает, а в Pycharm нет)

Tags: python, pycharm

При запуске в консоли всё работает, всё выводит,

```
> python3.4 t1.py
```

выводит:

```
signal8 - 0  signal9 -  0  signal11 -  0  signal22 -  0 signal22 -  0 signal25 -  0
```

А если в Pycharm, то нет. Он его формирует, наверное, как обьект. Вопрос в том, как вывести то, что получаю: `subprocess`, `stdout`?

**t1.py**

```
import subprocess

print ("Start program")

def startProgram(cmd):
  PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
  return p


cmd = r'ssh root@10.6.13.11 "/usr/bin/python3.2 -u /home/pi/priem2.py"'
startProgram(cmd)
```

**priem2.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
time.sleep(0.1)
signal22=GPIO.input(22)
signal23=GPIO.input(23)
signal25=GPIO.input(25)
signal9=GPIO.input(9)
signal11=GPIO.input(11)
signal8=GPIO.input(8)
GPIO.cleanup()

print(' signal8 -', signal8,' signal9 - ', signal9,' signal11 - ', signal11,' signal22 - ', signal22, 'signal22 - ', signal23, 'signal25 - ', signal25)
```

Comment: Возможно `GPIO`, `subprocess` модули не нужны, чтобы продемонстрировать проблему, если PyCharm не умеет показывать вывод `os.write(1, b'hello')`  команды, предполагая что `sys.__stdout__.fileno() == 1`. [Вот код, который перенаправляет вывод на уровне файловых дескрипторов](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) -- он демонстрирует, что замещение `sys.stdout` не достаточно, чтобы перенаправить весь стандартный вывод.

Comment: Может просто print прописать?
`print(startProgram(cmd))`

Answer (score 1):

Для получения `stdout` в переменную в модуле `subprocess` есть функция `check_output`

```
import subprocess

print ("Start program")


def startProgram(cmd):
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = r'ssh root@10.6.13.11 "/usr/bin/python3.2 -u /home/pi/priem2.py"'
    print(startProgram(cmd))
```

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen` не ждет завершения вызванного процесса, поэтому следует попробовать так

```
import subprocess

print ("Start program")

def startProgram(cmd):
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  return p


cmd = r'ssh root@10.6.13.11 "/usr/bin/python3.2 -u /home/pi/priem2.py"'
p = startProgram(cmd)
print(p.communicate()[0])
```

Comment: дело не в том что ждёт или не ждёт, а куда вывод направлен: обратите внимание вы добавили `stdout=PIPE`. Проще тогда уж: `print(subprocess.getoutput(cmd))` (запустить shell, выполнить команду, перехватить весь вывод в строке, вывести строку в `sys.stdout`).